# How to manually add dependencies to Gradle's MavenPom/MavenPublication?

Tags: gradle

I am working on a plugin.  This plugin gets attached to a project that does not apply the `java` plugin nor the `java-library` plugin but which should functionally "look" like a Java project[1]. Which means that it should publish a POM including dependencies.  The exact dependencies are known and have been collected in a `Configuration`.

However, I cannot figure out how to manually attach dependencies to the MavenPublication such that they make it into the published pom (aside from directly editing the pom xml).

```
MavenPublication shadowMavenPublication = publishingExtension.getPublications().create( "mavenShadowArtifacts", MavenPublication.class );
// `shadowPublishArtifact` is a class defined in the plugin
shadowMavenPublication.artifact(
        shadowPublishArtifact.getFile(),
        (mavenArtifact) -> {
                mavenArtifact.setClassifier( shadowPublishArtifact.getClassifier() );
                mavenArtifact.setExtension( shadowPublishArtifact.getExtension() );
        }
);
```

So at this point I have the `MavenPublication` and added my custom artifact to it.  Internally this `MavenPublication` contains a number of "dependencies" as instances of `MavenDependency`.  E.g. `DefaultMavenPublication#runtimeDependencies`, `DefaultMavenPublication#apiDependencies`, ...  But those are things defined on internal-only contracts.

Using just public APIs, how can I add dependencies to get added to the pom?

P.S. As a bonus, answer the question on the [Gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/add-dependencies-to-a-mavenpublication-ivypublication/40062) and get points there too! :D

P.S.S. These dependencies come from another project (hibernate-core) in a multi-project build.  The user has configured those dependencies themselves.  I just "consume" those dependencies with a series of "dependency substitutions".  That "source project" defines some exclusions to its dependencies.  How can I access those exclusions do be able to transfer them to the dependencies I am creating for this copy project (hibernate-core-jakarta)?

Thanks!

[1] Its a long back-story, but the gist is that this plugin integrates the JakartaTransformer.  The project is completely generated using the transformer.  The tasks added by those 2 plugins cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, dependencies are attached to the POM by evaluating the configurations of a [software component](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/component/SoftwareComponent.html): [`MavenPublication.from(SoftwareComponent)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/MavenPublication.html#from-org.gradle.api.component.SoftwareComponent-) (source: [`DefaultMavenPublication`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/5ec3f672ed600a86280be490395d70b7bc634862/subprojects/maven/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/publish/maven/internal/publication/DefaultMavenPublication.java#L286)).

The idea would be to provide a customized software component. This is only possible through a custom plugin, according to [Creating and publishing custom components](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_customization.html#sec:publishing-custom-components).

Comment: This is what I was afraid of.  Creating  new kind of software-component seems super non-trivial at best.

Answer (score 0):

[MavenPublication](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication.html) class has `pom` property - You need to construct (or provide in Your plugin some API for that purpose) pom with all necessary dependencies. It will be published alongside with artifact.

Comment: Yes, pom gives access to the XML.  And yes I could manually add the dependencies via editing the XML.  As I mentioned in the question, I'd prefer to avoid manually editing the XML for I would think obvious reasons

Comment: And exposing the pom through my plugin is not what I am asking.  As I mentioned, I already know the dependencies and have them as a Configuration.  I just need to get that Configuration contents into the XML